# Catch-22 when SQL Server CE database is full and trying to delete

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server CE database that is using the maximum database size of 4096kB. When I insert a row I get, as expected, the following error:

> The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size.
>   This setting takes effect on the first concurrent database connection
>   only. [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 4092 ]

So, I am trying to handle this by just deleting some rows, issuing a normal `SqlCeCommand`. The problem is that even the delete command, executed through `ExecuteNonQuery`, throws this error now when it is full.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying a command line tool like [sqlcecmd](https://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com/) to shrink your database, freeing up space to reduce its overall size? This should free up enough space for you to then delete any extraneous rows you have.

```
sqlcecmd.exe -d "Data Source=C:\YourDatabase.sdf" -e shrink
```

If you are running into this problem, it is time to switch to a SQL platform that can handle larger databases (SQL Server being the obvious example).

**EDIT**
If you are utilizing a `SqlCeEngine` object, it appears you can do this [programmatically](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171752%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) as well:

```
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = C:\YourDatabase.sdf");
engine.Shrink();
```

Comment: I did try to shrink it with SqlCeEngine and indeed it shrank a percentage or two but still the same problem when running a query.